# how to map char to int in java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm very new to programming and can't resolve the following problem.

I have a list of coordinates in type char that I need to transfer to numbers (type int). So for example char a should be int 0, char b - int 1 etc. So I build the following code using a switch statement. I want to call it as a method but I keep getting the following error: this method must return a result of type int. Could somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong? I've also tried using return instead of int .. = 0; but that didn't help either.

```
    int x () {
        char ch = 'c';
        switch (ch)
        { 
        case 'a': 
            int a = 0;
            break; 
        case 'b': 
            int b = 1;
            break; 
        case 'c': 
            int c = 2;
            System.out.println(c); 
            break; 
        case 'd': 
            int d = 3;
            break; 
        case 'e': 
            int e = 4;
            break; 
        case 'f': 
            int f = 5;
            break; 
        case 'g': 
            int g = 6;
            break; 
        case 'h': 
            int h = 7;
            break; 
        }   
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing `int a = 0`, `int b = 1` etc. You should just write `return 0;`, `return 1;` etc. And you don't need the breaks.

Comment: Then you don't need the breaks, as he/she/whatever does it, it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your chars are just the same you mentioned you can use something like this.

```
static int toNumber(char chr) {
        return (chr - 97);
    }
```

The concept is this: a char is encoded as a byte, which is a number. Check out a related [ASCII table](https://www.ascii-code.com/) where you can see that 'a' has the value 97 (decimal), 'b' has 98... So if we subtract 97 from all our chars we can reach the desired values.

```
    char   byte(decimal)   char value -97
    a        97                  0
    b        98                  1
    ...      ...                ...
    z        122                 24
```

But the problem with your function is the fact that the return statement was missing. You can make it work by changing it to this

```
int x() {
    char ch = 'c';
    int value = 0;
    switch (ch) {
        case 'a':
            value = 0;
            break;
        case 'b':
            value = 1;
            break;
        case 'c':
            value = 2;
            System.out.println(c);
            break;
        case 'd':
            value = 3;
            break;
        case 'e':
            value = 4;
            break;
        case 'f':
            value = 5;
            break;
        case 'g':
            value = 6;
            break;
        case 'h':
            value = 7;
            break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: A somehow related assignemt one can frequently see is [is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347443/need-to-fix-for-loop/58348067#58348067), also deals with char/byte tricks, which I tried to make as transparent as possible in the very looong answer at the end.

Comment: Under the hood a number of implicit type conversions take place, from char 'a' to byte 97 to byte (97-97=0) to int for the return value 0(byte) -> 0(int) if I'm not mistaken. You can find more info and examples [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-java-examples/) and the complete oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can get it different ways.

```
int x = Character.getNumericValue('a');
```

or,

```
char a = 'a';
int x = a;
```

or,

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf('a'));
```