# Basic question about for loop with char array (Java)

Tags: java

My assignment is to go through a users input and convert it to a total sum. Idea is to change all the letters to a corresponding number, as in `a = 1` and so on.

Really basic stuff but I'm at a loss, my idea was to convert the users response to a char array and then loop through each char and then use a switch or multiple loops to get the value but I can't even get a for loop to work because I'm getting `"Cannot invoke charAt(int) on the array type char[]"`.

```
public class question3 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner userTypes = new Scanner(System.in);

        String wordValue;
        System.out.print("Please enter a string");
        wordValue = userTypes.next();

        String lowerCase;
        lowerCase = wordValue.toLowerCase();

        char[] arrayConvert = lowerCase.toCharArray();

        System.out.println(arrayConvert);
        int fullNumber;
        System.out.print("Please enter an int");
        fullNumber = userTypes.nextInt();

        double decimalNumber;
        System.out.print("Please enter a double");
        decimalNumber = userTypes.nextDouble();

        double totalNumber;
        totalNumber = fullNumber + decimalNumber;
        System.out.print("your result is " + totalNumber);

        for(int i=0; i< arrayConvert.length;i++) {
            if(arrayConvert.charAt(i)== ("a")){

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `char[]` doesn't have a method `charAt` defined, only String type has. You access array elements by index, eg `arrayConvert[i] == 'a'`. But beware, in your code you use double quotes `("a")` and this will give you a String, not a char. Use single quotes instead, and omit the redundant braces as in `'a'`. If you want to compare Strings use `"aSring".equals("anotherString")`. It pays off getting into the details of the [String/Char/Integer/Byte business](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347443/need-to-fix-for-loop/58348067#58348067).

Comment: Arrays allow us to access their content via `array[index]` syntax. `charAt` belongs to `String` class which is NOT `char[]` (String can *contain* `char[]` internally). But since you are already aware of `charAt` why not invoke it on String directly? Why do you create an array in the first place? Also `"..."` is String literal, but result of `charAt` is `char` so you should compare it with other `char`. In other words `charAt(i)== ("a")` should be more like `charAt(i)== 'a'`.

Comment: Thanks, spot on with your answer

Comment: BTW `char` type is really a numeric type which holds *number* representing position of character in Unicode Table. So for instance char representing [`'a'`](https://unicode-table.com/en/0061/) really holds `97`. And numbers can be added to each other so to map `a->1`, `b->2` you can calculate difference between your character and `'a'` and increase it by 1 like `'a'-'a'+1 = 0+1 = 1` `'b'-'a'+1 = 1+1 = 2` etc.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test your code, but `charAt` isn't a char[] method. Try this:

```
for(int i=0; i< arrayConvert.length;i++) {
    if(arrayConvert[i] == 'a'){

    }
}
```

Comment: Got 'Incompatible operand types char and String', actually i changed to single quotes and it seems to work, cheers

Comment: Cheers, pal, but still it would pay off to get familiar with the difference between a String and a char (and a byte perhaps), that's a [very common issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347443/need-to-fix-for-loop/58348067#58348067).

Answer (score 0):

My first question, Why do you want to get a `string` and converting into `int` or `long`. It looks you need to do code for all the inputs (i,e- if you want to get 1000 values as inputs then you need to write code stdout and next* operation for 1000 times.

Try the below one which will help users to choose their choice of inputs and get the sum value of those inputs.

*SumGivenInputs.java*

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumGivenInputs {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter the number of inputs\n");
       int noOfInput = scan.nextInt();

       System.out.printf("Enter the %d input%s \n", noOfInput, noOfInput > 1 ? "s one by one" : "");
       Integer[] inputList = new Integer[noOfInput];
       for (int i = 0; i < noOfInput; i++) {
           inputList[i] = scan.nextInt();
       }
       int result = 0;
       for (Integer input : Arrays.asList(inputList)) {
           result += input;
       }
       System.out.printf("Sum = %s", result);
   }
}
```

*Output:*

```
Enter the number of inputs
5
Enter the 5 inputs one by one 
10
20
30
5
50
Sum = 115
```